# Remove white space between two plots resulting from grid.arrange function in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics

I'd like to eliminate the white space between my two forest plots that I plotted side-by-side using grid.arrange().

*Before you vote down or redirect - Before asking this question, I have spent hours attempting every solution posed in each of the responses I've seen here for similar questions without achieving my desired result.*

First, here is my dataset and code:

```
library(meta)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

df <- structure(list(study    = 1:7,
                     sens     = c(0.88, 0.86, 0.75, 0.9, 0.91, 0.93, 0.98),
                     sens.se  = c(0.13, 0.08, 0.2, 0.06, 0.13, 0.15, 0.66),
                     sens2    = c(0.76, 0.68, 0.9, 0.82, 0.76, 0.85, 0.76),
                     sens.se2 = c(0.14, 0.08, 0.2, 0.06, 0.14, 0.15, 0.66)),
                class = "data.frame",
                row.names = c(NA, -7L))

## setting up meta-analysis model using library(meta)
res1 <- metagen(TE=sens, seTE=sens.se, data=df, studlab=study)
res2 <- metagen(TE=sens2, seTE=sens.se2, data=df, studlab=study)

## changing plots to grid graphical objects to use grid.arrange
fp1 <- grid.grabExpr(forest(res1, data=df, method.tau="REML", 
                            comb.random=TRUE, leftcols="studlab",
                            rightcols=c("effect", "ci")))
fp2 <- grid.grabExpr(forest(res2, data=df, method.tau="REML", 
                            comb.random=TRUE, leftcols="studlab",
                            rightcols=c("effect", "ci")))

## arranging plots side by side:
grid.arrange(fp1, fp2, ncol = 2)
```

When I have attempted to use code suggested in responses to similar questions, I get the "only grobs allowed in gList" error code, even though R recognizes the plots as "gTrees" because I used the grid.grabExpr function. I've tried coercing the gTrees into grobs via:

```
p1 <- as.grob(fp1)
p2 <- as.grob(fp2)
```

, which only creates null values in the global environment.

I would greatly appreciate some help with this!

Comment: It's not a gap that you are seeing necessarily. If you shrink the plot in the graphics device you should see that gap disappear and the plots will start to overlap. The package author used static sized units for the sizes of their plot elements, not relative ("cm" instead of "npc"). Setting what units I can to relative in `forest()` does not seem to fix the issue, but make it worse. With static units, I think you are SOL here for side-by-side scaling. Maybe someone else knows a good trick.

Comment: You may want to have a look at `patchwork`: `install.packages("devtools");
devtools::install_github("thomasp85/patchwork")`. With it, you can "add" (gg)plots together, with smaller blank spaces in between.

Comment: Thanks, both of you. PavoDive, I'd like to use that function, but I'm still having trouble with my plots not being recognized as grobs. Do you have any suggestions for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this does what you are looking for:

```
grid.grabExpr(
  forest(
    res1, data=df, method.tau="REML", 
    comb.random=TRUE, leftcols="studlab",
    rightcols=c("effect", "ci")
  ),
  height = 1, width = 2
) -> fp1

grid.grabExpr(
  forest(
    res2, data=df, method.tau="REML", 
    comb.random=TRUE, leftcols="studlab",
    rightcols=c("effect", "ci")
  ),
  height = 1, width = 2
) -> fp2

grid.arrange(fp1, fp2, ncol = 2, vp=viewport(width=1, height=1, clip = TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!  Brilliant solution.